# VB.Net sqlconnection invalidoperationexception The connection is already open

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

When I start the project it works fine, the datagridview is working fine, it shows the columns from the xampp database. But when I click the add button It shows this error:

> sqlconnection invalidoperationexception The connection is already open

here is the complete exception detail:

```
"System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233079
 Message=The connection is already open.
Source=MySql.Data
 StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at Library.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Aron\Desktop\Programming\Library\Library\Form1.vb:line 40
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
   at Library.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException: "
```

and here is my full code (im a beginner sorry)

```vb
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim ServerString As String = "Server = localhost;User Id 
    =root;Password=;Database=library"
    Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(ServerString)

    Sub load()
        Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM books"
        Dim adpt As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, SQLConnection)
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        adpt.Fill(ds, "EMP")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        SQLConnection.Close()
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        load()
    End Sub
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Dim gridrow As DataGridViewRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow
        Try
            TextBox1.Text = gridrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            TextBox5.Text = gridrow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
            TextBox2.Text = gridrow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            TextBox3.Text = gridrow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()
            TextBox4.Text = gridrow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()
            TextBox6.Text = gridrow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

        SQLConnection.Open()
        Try
            cmd = SQLConnection.CreateCommand
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Books(Group,Book_Name,Publisher,Author,Publishing_Year)VALUES(@Group,@Book_Name,@Publisher,@Author,@Publishing_Year);"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", TextBox5.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_Name", TextBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", TextBox4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publishing_Year", TextBox6.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            load()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        SQLConnection.Open()
        Try
            cmd = SQLConnection.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "update Books set Group=@Group, Book_Name=@Book_Name, Publisher=@Publisher, Author=@Author, Publishing_Year=@Publishing_Year where Book_ID=@Book_ID ;"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_ID", TextBox1.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Group", TextBox5.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_Name", TextBox2.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publisher", TextBox3.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Author", TextBox4.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Publishing_Year", TextBox6.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            load()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
        SQLConnection.Open()
        Try
            cmd = SQLConnection.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Books WHERE Book_ID=@Book_ID;"
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Book_ID", TextBox1.Text)
            TextBox1.Clear()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            load()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button9_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        If DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index < DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1).Selected = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This site is not a substitute for debugging your own code. If you don't know how, now is the time to learn. If the error message is telling you that you're trying to open a connection that is already open then the obvious thing to do is to focus on the places that you are opening a connection and make sure that you're closing it again when you're done with it. Place breakpoints at the appropriate places and step through the code as required. The issue should be obvious because it is obvious whether a connection is open or closed while debugging properly.

Comment: Here's a tip: put something in your `Catch` blocks and put a breakpoint there.

Comment: Connections are meant to be created, used and disposed of in the smallest scope possible.  You are using the same connection over and over.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the replies, finally got it. Changed the "Group"into "Subject"...